# Disable form2 to move out of form1

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have two forms . Form1 and Form2

Form1 is a 600x500 and form2 is 300x250.

Form1 is allways open and when i open form2 it should be on top of form1. How to disable form2 to move out of width form1

Like this
[image]

Not like this
[image]

So it should be re sizable but unable to move out of edges form1.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [MDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thanks for your fast answer. Take a look on this. On Form1 i set IsMdiContainer = True  .. Add a menu strip and on click event i add this code "   `Private Sub RosterManagementToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RosterManagementToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim f1 As New FrmRoster
        f1.MdiParent = Me
        FrmRoster.Show()
    End Sub`" It still won't open inside it it goes under the menu strip and looks like this [link](http://pokit.org/get/?0a405cad95490c4c07ecb169ea4e3cf7.jpg)

Ah edit: I just need to lock the menu strip on the do

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå i just edited . Leave MDI link as answer and i will accept it. I did it with MDI thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you need to dock the controls parented to the mdi client.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I finished problem by using MDI Child Forms. You can post it as answer if you want so i can resolve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not planning to use **[MDI Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx)**

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.Left = Form1.Location.X
    Me.Top = Form1.Location.Y + 30
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    'check position
    Dim topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, BottomRight As Point
    With Form1
        topLeft = New Point(.Location.X, .Location.Y + 30)
        topRight = New Point(.Location.X + .Width, .Location.Y + 30)
        bottomLeft = New Point(.Location.X, .Location.Y + .Height)
        'BottomRight = New Point(.Location.X + .Location.Y + .Height)
    End With
    Dim mytopLeft, mytopRight, mybottomLeft, myBottomRight As Point
    With Me
        mytopLeft = New Point(.Location.X, .Location.Y)
        mytopRight = New Point(.Location.X + .Width, .Location.Y)
        mybottomLeft = New Point(.Location.X, .Location.Y + .Height)
        'myBottomRight = New Point(.Location.X + .Location.Y + .Height)
    End With

    If topLeft.X > mytopLeft.X Then
        Me.Location = New Point(topLeft.X, Me.Location.Y)
        Me.Text = "topLeftX"
    End If
    If topLeft.Y > mytopLeft.Y Then
        Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X, topLeft.Y)
        Me.Text = "topLeftY"
    End If

    If topRight.X < mytopRight.X Then
        Me.Location = New Point(topRight.X - Me.Width, Me.Location.Y)
        Me.Text = "topRightX"
    End If

    If bottomLeft.Y < mybottomLeft.Y Then
        Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X, bottomLeft.Y - Me.Height)
        Me.Text = "bottomLeftY"
    End If
End Sub
```